# How to get the name of checkbox that I checked in libreoffice calc (macro)?

Tags: libreoffice

I have more than 40 check-boxes in a single calc sheet, and I don't want to code each one of them. I just want a clear working code to **get the name of checkbox**.

In this program I have to manually type the name for the check-box within the macro code:

```
A="CheckBox1"
```

This is all I have so far:

```vb
Sub Marco1
    Dim ocheckbox1
    Dim oForm
    Dim A
    A="CheckBox1"
    oForm = ThisComponent.Sheets(0).DrawPage.Forms.getByIndex(0)
    ocheckbox1 = oForm.getByName(A)
    if ocheckbox1.State = "0" then
        if MsgBox ("Are you sure ?Note: It can't be re-edited", 292) = 6 then
            ocheckbox1.Label = "Checked"
            ocheckbox1.Enabled="False"
        else
            ocheckbox1.Label = "Not Checked"
        End if
    End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the macro is triggered by interaction with the checkbox:

```
Sub Macro1 (oEvent As Object)
    Dim oCheckbox1 As Object
    Dim sCheckbox1Name As String

    oCheckbox1 = oEvent.source.model
    sCheckbox1Name = oCheckbox1.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I would also like to know which book did you use to learn about macro (open office).

Comment: OpenOffice Macros Explained by Andrew Pitonyak is an excellent book.  He has made it available as a [free download](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).  The API is also documented on the [OpenOffice website](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/module-ix.html). When documentation is lacking, object inspection tools [XRay](http://bernard.marcelly.perso.sfr.fr/index2.html) or [MRI](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/mri-uno-object-inspection-tool) save the day. Also see this [MRI tutorial](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=49294)